# Reject words with Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
^\/projects*
```

Which matches:

```
/projects
/projects/239/jobs/233
```

I would like to not match a string that after `/projects` contains, somewhere, the word `jobs` or `members` ... How can I do this?

Comment: In what language/tool are you using this regex?

Comment: I am using this regex in a C# project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead :

i.e. :

```
^\/projects(?!.*jobs|.*members).*$
```

Working example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Px9owP/1)